# How can I get as much of the text into a DIV row as possible?

Tags: html, css

I have a row (implemented with a div), which has a fixed width and height. The row contains three elements (in spans) of which the first two are fixed width. The third element in the row contains a span and some text. The problem is that when the text is too long, the entire span drops down to the next line. How can I prevent this behavior to have as much of that span display on the line as possible.

Constraints:

1. The whatever is too long should overflow to the right.
2. This needs to be a css solution only, no javascript/jQuery
3. The html has to stay the same (as per 2).

Here is a jsFiddle to see what I mean and play with to your liking.

http://jsfiddle.net/59YU5/1/

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't fully understood your problem

Comment: Do you actually want the span three to contain more text?

Comment: No, I am talking about positioning. I want span three to be on the same line as one and two but just overflow to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I fully understood what you want, but try adding `white-space: nowrap;` to the problematic span.

EDIT2

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/59YU5/7/)

Comment: That doesnt help, the problem is that the span itself is wrapping. Look at the fiddle and see how the green box and the text are on the next line outside the row. Thats the problem.

Comment: Right, in your example the green box and text are still outside the grey box. It should be in the grey box overflowing to the right.

Comment: @chacham15 do you want the text not to pass the grey box?

Comment: I want as much of it as possible to be in the grey box. The rest should overflow to the right (where it can be hidden with overflow properties)

Comment: @Shomz I want it to look like that BUT have the grey box's width be smaller (i.e. have the text go out of the box to the right)

Comment: Just set the #row width to something like 200px. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/r2cT3/

Set to your problematic span (**#three**):  `white-space: nowrap;` and `max-width` to your grey box which is the main div.

Comment: +1 Yes, this works too but Shomz solution works a little better for my situation, thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

```
.span-class{
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

perhaps

or change font-size. letter-spacing may be usefull. remember to remove all padding from the span, incase that is lowering it's content area.

short answer short of changing the box contents you can't force something of one size into a box that is to small to hold it.

Comment: I want as much of it to be in the box as possible, the rest should overflow out of the box to the right

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to keep the original width's. But I've made some changes to your css. note the overflow and nowrap for element #three: http://jsfiddle.net/SRgND/2/

Comment: Well, increasing the width of the div defeats the purpose, I want to make the span overflow to the right.